# Upgrade to Hibernate 3.6 errors with reverse engineering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate3

I have found a few threads on various sites that seem to touch on this problem, but I am having no luck. It seems as though it simply can not be done. I get the 
`Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings, but class was expected` error. Looking at the [compatability matrix](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix)  that is [Shown in this thread.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1004766) it seems that I can't use reveng unless I downgrade. But this can not seem right.

When I started upgrading everything worked, and now I am getting that same error. I made sure not to have two different jars with the same name on my class path. I have the following jars:

```
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-tools.jar    
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
other various jars not dealing with hibernate..
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
    ...   
    hibernatetool
    Executing Hibernate Tool with a JDBC Configuration (for reverse engineering)
    1. task: hbm2hbmxml (Generates a set of hbm.xml files)     java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings, but class was expected
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings, but class was expected
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.MappingsDatabaseCollector.getTable(MappingsDatabaseCollector.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCBinder.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readFromDatabase(JDBCBinder.java:94)
    ...
```

ant:

```
<taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="classpath" />
...
 <hibernatetool>
    <jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="${conf.dir}/${dbName}_hibernate-template.cfg.xml" packagename="myPackageName" revengfile="${conf.dir}/hibernate.reveng.xml" reversestrategy="com.capitaliq.loader.dev.codegen.HibernateReverseStrategy" detectmanytomany="false" />
    <hbm2hbmxml destdir="${srcGen.dir}" />
    <!-- Generate new hibernate.cfg.xml including new POJOs-->
    <!--'destdir' is relative to 'packagename' configuration-->
    <hbm2cfgxml ejb3="false" destdir="${conf.dir}" />
</hibernatetool>

<!-- Generate java POJOs from mapping files-->
<hibernatetool> <!--Line 384-->
    <configuration configurationfile="${conf.dir}/${dbName}_hibernate-template.cfg.xml">
        <fileset dir="${orm.pkg.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.hbm.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </configuration>
    <!--'destdir' is relative to 'packagename' configuration-->
    <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="false" destdir="${srcGen.dir}" />
</hibernatetool>
```

Any help would be great; this computer is about to get thrown. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [link. Max](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1008336), one of the contributors to hibernate, states (near the bottom of the thread):

"The problem is that Hibernate 3.6 has a class change from class to interface which means it is source compatible but not binary compatible with Hibernate Tools.

That plus other binary changes causes this problem and is recorded in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-8071

***Thus the "workaround" is when you need to generate code with hibernate tools then don't include hibernate 3.6 on the classpath; the resulting code can be used fine with 3.6 afterwards.***

The challenge is that if we added 3.6 support we would loose 3.3-3.5 support too.
Thus for now we are not updating but will try and see what we can do going forward."

It appears I was trying to do the impossible. Though I am glad I finally have an answer, I regret to say it is not the one I hoped it would be.

One can not have the two jars on the same classpath, even though the are dependent on one another. If you want to reverse engineer some hibernate code, best not have hibernate version 3.6!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the jars don't have the same name does not mean they cannot contain the exact same classes.

Hibernate and SLF4J usually require only one jar to be used. The other jars usually contain part of the classes from the large main jar and maybe some extra classes for a specific task.

I would start by removing `hibernate-tools.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` and maybe even `commons-logging-1.0.4.jar` and then see if you get `ClassNotFoundException` you can add the specific required jar.

Comment: AFAIK hibernate-tools.jar is the only jar that contains org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.  For Hib 3.6+ you should use EnversHibernateToolTask (which extends HibernateToolTask), but that means you still need to include the hibernate-tools.jar and doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: Both of those gave me different class not found exceptions, pertaining to both of the jars i removed. And as sqrfv pointed out, I need to have hibernate-tools in there in order to get to the HibernateToolTask base class.

Comment: what version of hibernate-tools.jar are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not specify in the meta-inf does not specify. But I would hazard a guess at the one in 3.3 or 3.2.

Comment: My guess is that you are using the wrong version. For example, I know that hibernate-3.3.2.jar goes with hibernate-tools-3.2.4.GA.jar. do you know the hibernate3.jar version?

Comment: the wrong version of tools? They seem not have a compatible version of  the tools jar. But my hibernate3.jar is version 3.6.10, and I need to keep it 3.6 because they introduced functionality in 3.6 that I need, that is why I upgraded.

Comment: where did you dl the tools jar? are you using eclipse?

Comment: intellij. And I think I have answered this query on my own research. Thanks so much for your help @ftom2